Apart Area Chart not showing Data if type Datetime is selected
I am tryng to display data using Apex Chart, the chart is working fine dynamically if its only DATE type. When I use date range search (switching to DATETIME dynamically) to query database the AREA chart does not show chart but only shows figures when you hover on the chart, on the other hand if i change type to BAR it works fine.
What could be wrong? What am I missing?
Please see the image here attached

here is the result when i click view source. It shows data is available, but the visuals are not showing


var options = {
  series: [{
      name: "Value1 Label",
      data: ["330.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    },
    {
      name: "Value2 Label",
      data: ["310.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    },
    {
      name: "Value3 Label",
      data: ["230.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    },
    {
      name: "Value4 Label",
      data: ["320.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    },
    {
      name: "Value5 Label",
      data: ["330.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    },
    {
      name: "Value6 Label",
      data: ["320.00", "0.00", "0.00"]
    }
  ],
  chart: {
    height: 350,
    stacked: true,
    type: 'area'
  },
  dataLabels: {
    enabled: false
  },
  colors: ['#3078AF', '#AF3080', '#3C8337', '#A25267', '#EFA1EC', 'grey'],
  stroke: {
    curve: "smooth",
    lineCap: "round",
    width: 0
  },
  fill: {
    type: "solid"
  },
  xaxis: {
    type: "datetime",
    categories: ["2024-03-01", "2024-03-02", "2024-03-03"],
    labels: {
      style: {
        //colors: colors.mutedColor,
        cssClass: "text-muted",
        //fontFamily: base.defaultFontFamily
      }
    },
  },
  yaxis: {
    labels: {
      style: {
        //colors: colors.mutedColor,
        cssClass: "text-muted",
        //fontFamily: base.defaultFontFamily
      }
    },
  },
  legend: {
    position: "bottom",
    horizontalAlign: 'center',
    //fontFamily: base.defaultFontFamily,
    fontWeight: 400,
    labels: {
      //colors: colors.mutedColor
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    x: {
      format: 'dd/MM/yy HH:mm'
    },
  },
};

var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#areaChart"), options);
chart.render();
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/apexcharts"></script>
<br/>
<br/>
<div id="areaChart"></div>




Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

@NicoHaase Not sure if its php or JS, if you check on the picture i added, On the RIGHT is a BAR type working fine with the same php code. On the Left is an AREA chart only showing series figures on hover. If I change chart type to BAR it works

If you are not sure, please check it

As per the result and what i have tried. Problem points to JS

If so, then to make the question more focused and provide a [mre] of the issue you should remove the PHP code and just replace with some sample data to feed into the chart, which would demonstrate the issue in isolation. (That would also help you, and us, to prove that PHP code isn't a factor in the probelm).

@ADyson i have added the result when I view source code, hope this helps with my question

Yep that's much better. Can you now turn it into a runnable snippet, so we can try it for ourselves?

It doesn't run, though. Did you test it? The point is that it could actually show the chart, and thus demonstrate the issue in real life. Also I expect the 2nd snippet can be removed, since that also involves embedded PHP? Other than that it's simply a repeat of the 1st one as far as I can see?

ok let me remove the second one

I made it actually execute for you. Does that now demonstrate your issue when you run it? I can't see that it does.

does this mean that problem lies with php?

Well, possibly yes. You mentioned something about it being triggered when searching? Does that mean the search is returning different data than is shown in your sample, perhaps? Have you debugged that? Also how is the search being triggered? It's far from obvious, based on the code provided, how that could be done. Like I said earlier, you need to make sure you provide a [mre] of the issue - and carefully test what you post, before you post it, to ensure that's the case. We removed the PHP because you stated you didn't think the PHP was relevant - but it's not clear on what basis you said that

I use two HTML input date tags to pas data to php then query based on the range of dates selected. change time to UNIX using strtotime then to the normal date time. Would you like me to add the php?

I tested the encoded json data and i didn't see anything wrong. The Bar Chart is working fine using same json result

I'd like you to provide a [mre] of the issue. You need to carefully test and look at your code to work out what that needs to consist of in order to clearly demonstrate the problem you're asking about - it maybe be JS, or PHP, or a combination of both, plus relevant some sample source data, any error messages, or noticeable unexpected behaviour, specific variable values at points in the process, etc. If it involves PHP it won't be possible to make a fully runnable snippet, but it should be possible for us to follow the steps needed to reproduce the bug, from end to end.

Ok thanks @ADyson let me reanalyse my PHP code to see if i can find where the problem is.

Thanks @ADyson, You were right!! Problem lies with PHP I found where the problem is. i just had to put DATE RANGE  search outside this  for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {} so this becomes if(){date range code} else{  for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {}}

That's great, glad you found it. If you think the solution would be useful to others with a similar issue (which is really the purpose of Stackoverflow, after all) then please a) edit the question to provide the [mre] we talked about, and b) post an Answer below showing how you resolved the issue. (Adding a comment doesn't really help because they can't be searched, and you can't get reputation points when people vote on them). See also [answer]. Thankyou!

I was able to get a solution thanks to help here. Problem is i was looping DATERANGE search query inside months search query.
my final answer looks like this
if(!empty($from_date) || !empty($to_date)) { 
     // Date Range Query here
     array_push($values, number_format( sprintf( '%.2f', $values), 2, '.', '' ));   

      } 

    else{
      for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {
     // search based on months query.
     array_push($values, number_format( sprintf( '%.2f', $values), 2, '.', '' )); 
    //  $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
    // $month =  date('M', mktime(0, 0, 0, $m, 1));
   array_push($months, $month);  
    }

    }
    
    if(!empty($from_date) || !empty($to_date)) {
      // $months = json_encode($dateRangeArray);
    }
    else{
      // $months = json_encode($months);
    }

